# How do I verify a file uploaded with php doesn't contain an executable binary?

Tags: php, security

Using a simple firefox addon, a hacker can change the mime type of any file they want to upload, bypassing your file type checker.

Hackers can then use a program like GIMP to embed a php script inside the binary data of an image, audio or any other file.

How can I check for this, and prevent it?

Comment: Where is the threat? If your file is saved without execute attribute, the hacker won't be able to run it anyway.

Comment: Additionaly upload your files to dir that is not parsed by php parser.

Comment: @user4035 I cannot tell you where the thrreat is, because I use php to upload .mp3 files which are executed within a Flash or HTML5 player, and I still got hacked. I know I'm definitely safe from SQLi and XSS, so it must be from a file upload.

Comment: Flash and HTML5 are executed on the client side. So they can't hack you through it. Check the mp3 files permissions: they must not be executed or ran through php.

Comment: @user4035 It wasn't a typical hack. They faked a mime type in order to upload a _symlink_ Linux shortcut, and then they used that to themselves provide access to the whole ENTIRE server. From that, they could then upload anything they wanted, wherever they wanted, via FTP, provided they had a hosting account elsewhere on the shared server.

Comment: @desbest Your case it very interesting. They uploaded a symlink to what file? How could they access your server directory via a symlink? On shared hostings the users can't access the directories of the other users. Plz, give the detailed info, if you can.

Comment: There was a symlink on my hosting account that allowed access to the entire server. In this instance, I could access the directories of the other users, and the whole server as well.

Comment: I have started a thread about your case on linuxquestions: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=4839028. And we are sure, that the cause of hack was not the symlink, but incorrectly set rights to your directory by the administrators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)() to get the actual mime type of the file instead of the value transmitted by the client browser.

Then you can use a  library such as [php-ClamAV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-clamav/) that allows to perform virus-scans in PHP.

You can discard any file extension except those you expect (eg .png, .jpg, etc if you're expecting images).
In the specific case of images, you could also neutralize images by modifying them (eg slightly resize them, modify the compression rate, something that would modify the data and neutralize any executable).

Finally of course, take of not giving the execution right to the file. But contrary to what is said in the comments, this will not really protect you. If the hacker finds a way to run php file though an injection for instance, he'll be able to chmod the file and get the execution right (and even run it).

A good practice is also to always rename the file in an unpredictable way. If it is not meant to be accessed by clients after upload, send the files in a folder where directory browsing is disabled.