# Wrap an executable inside an image

Tags: php, image, security, validation, user-input

I'm hardening a PHP web application where untrusted users can upload images. I need to make sure that the uploaded files actually are 100% valid, harmless images.

I'm already validating the file server-side with [finfo](http://php.net/manual/it/ref.fileinfo.php) and [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php). I'm not trusting the user-provided file-extensions but I'm acquiring it with said functions instead.

Still, I read from multiple sources that is not that hard to "**wrap an executable inside an image**" and trick said functions in reporting it as a valid image. Right now I see no easy way to execute them afterwards, but I'd still prefer to discard them immediately: I worry, for example, that an attacker could upload a malicious JPEG-with-PHP-code, which would be harmless as of now, but the attacker could then exploit a second, unforeseen vulnerability to rename it as .php and run it on the server [as described here](http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070604/passing-malicious-php-through-getimagesize/).

Right now my main interest is in creating such a malicious image and see how my code react. Afterward I'll foucs on the countermeasures.

So... how do I "**wrap an executable inside an image**"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I verify a file uploaded with php doesn't contain an executable binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581425/how-do-i-verify-a-file-uploaded-with-php-doesnt-contain-an-executable-binary)

Comment: The proposed duplicate doesn't describe how to create the fake image.

Comment: But your ultimate goal is to prevent this from happening and not create your own malicious JPEG's I hope?

Comment: As I wrote: "Right now my main interest is in creating such a malicious image and see how my code react. Afterward I'll foucs on the countermeasures."

Comment: Yes and I won't help you with creating malicious code. Good luck though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, something like this should do the trick:

```
GIF89a<?php
echo 'hi';
```

This article provides some additional info http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070604/passing-malicious-php-through-getimagesize/

Here I found a software for modify EXIF data and add the executable code there: http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/13/php-code-injection-a-simple-virus-written-in-php-and-carried-in-a-jpeg-image/

HTH.